# SparkViewEngine: Using Url.Content in global variable in Application.Spark

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-variables, spark-view-engine

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with SparkViewEngine 1.1 and I get the error message ***An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Spark.Web.Mvc.SparkView.Url.get'*** when I use the following code in the Application.spark view file

```
<global baseImagePath='Url.Content(Context,"~/Content/_images")' type="string" />
```

What I am trying to accomplish is basically define a base image path as a global variable that can be referenced in the page templates.

For example, in Home/Index.spark, which uses the master Application.spark, I would have the following code snippet in the view

```
<a href="..."><img src="${baseImagePath}" alt="..." /></a>
```

As a workaround, I can set a hard-coded value when I set baseImagePath by doing `<global baseImagePath='"~/Content/_images"' type="string" />`, but I want to also be able to resolve the "~" before hand.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

**Edit**
I am adding my solution here per Rob's suggestions

In **Shared/_global.spark**, I added `<use namespace="System.Web" />`  so that I have access to the System.Web namespace.

In **Shared/Application.spark**, I added

```
<global baseImagePath='VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/_images")' type="string" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `Url.Content(...` is accessing the UrlHelper class in `System.Web.Mvc` from the SparkView instance. The problem is that when the `Application.spark` is being parsed for globals, you don't yet have an instance of a view because global variables are defined before the generated view class is instantiated. Therefore accessing and instance variable like `Url` from the view is not possible.

From the looks of it though, you're just trying to get an absolute path from a relative one. For this you could potentially just use the static [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class from `System.Web`.

There are a number of methods on there like `ToAbsolute(...)` that make life easier. Alternatively, you could get it from the `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(...)` method if you have the current context.

Hope that helps,
All the best,
Rob G

Comment: Thanks! Using the VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute method did it.